# 3D plot problem

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix $(A_{10*10})$ in which each elements of matrix states the value of the function $y=f(x,y)$. Since, $y$ shows the enclosed area between two squares, so I don't have the value of these elements in this area. Now my question is that how can I plot the $y$ in termes of $x,y$ in 2D or 3D using matlab while I don't have the values of $y$ in $A(3:5,3:5)$? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

put your data instead of A matrice

```
 A=rand(10,10);
 h = bar3(A);
 colormap jet
 colorbar
```

for change in color you can use 
this code :

```
 shading interp
 for i = 1:length(h)
     zdata = get(h(i),'ZData');
     set(h(i),'CData',zdata)
     set(h,'EdgeColor','k') 
 end
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you the values A(3:5,3:5) are undefined, set them to `NaN` and the plotting commands will ignore them. You can then use @AmirAlizadeh's approach with [`bar3`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bar3.html), or draw an image with [`imagesc`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html). The latter is perhaps less spectacular, but often clearer. In particular, with `bar3` it would be hard to see the "hole" in x=3:5, y=3:5.

```
A=rand(10,10); % example data...
A(3:5,3:5) = NaN; % ...no data here
imagesc(A)
colorbar
axis xy
xlabel 'x'
ylabel 'y'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To see negative values during X-Y-View (view similar to imagesc) you can define a function like this to change the color of the bars corresponding to their height:

function make_bar3_scaled_color(h)
%MAKE_BAR3_SCALED_COLOR changes the color of the bars in a BAR3 plot
%corresponding to their heigths.

```
for i = 1:length(h)
    zdata = get(h(i),'ZData');
    size_zdata = size(zdata);
    %zdata = ones(size_zdata);
    for j=0:6:(size_zdata(1)-6)
        akt_data = zdata(j+1:j+6,:);
        [max_akt_data max_pos] = max(abs(akt_data(:)));
        zdata(j+1:j+6,:) = akt_data(max_pos);
    end
    set(h(i),'CData',zdata);
end
```

end